# How to implement node_acl in mean stack with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, acl

I'd like to implement ACL with my MEAN application.  I have a few questions regarding the implementation.

1. How do I get acl with a mongodb backend instantiated in
   server.js so that I can use the same instance in my router and
   controllers?
2. Does it make sense to create an acl controller that an administrator
   can use to create and assign roles, and change permissions?
3. I would like all resources in my router.js to be exposed as acl
   resources with relevant actions.  Does this happen automatically
   when you add acl.middleware() to the route?
4. How can I define a permission like "edit own content"?

Here are a list of controller methods I have come up with to implement methods provided by ACL allowing an administrator to manage ACL settings:

- set_acl (roles, resources, permissions)
- remove_role (role)
- what_resources (role, [permissions])
- user_roles (userId)
- allowed_permissions (userId, [resources])
- add_user_roles (userId, roles)
- remove_user_roles (userId, roles)

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://npmjs.org/package/acl it works with mongo db as backend

Comment: The ACL npm is node_acl:  https://github.com/optimalbits/node_acl which I am considering currently.  Have you used it in any of your projects?  I'm looking for guidance with the MEAN stack.

Comment: yes, the only bad thing for mongodb is a very big size of data used by ACL (if we have 10 users, 10 documents, and 2 granties (read, write) - we have 200 records in ACL table). I think the better approach is using something unix like - every document have user id and group id, and there is groups of users. I managed to start writing thus system from scratch, but i was not sucessefull because of personal problems